# Error parsing parameter '--targets': Expected: '=', received: '{' for input:

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, aws-glue, aws-glue-connection

I am creating a crawler through AWS CLI in Glue, but facing issue.

Here's the CLI Command that i use

```
aws glue create-crawler \
--name "mytestcrawlernew" \
--role "arn:aws:iam::role/AWSGlueServiceRole-AWSGlueServiceRole" \
--database-name "mydb" \
--description "This is the test Crawler" \
--targets "JdbcTargets":{"ConnectionName":"RS_Connection"}
```

Am i doing anything wring, cause i am facing the subjected issue

Answer (score 2):

On the official documentation [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/comprehend/latest/dg/tutorial-reviews-tables.html), you can have a look at the proper syntax like in this example:

```
aws glue create-crawler 
--name comprehend-analysis-crawler
--role glue-iam-role-arn 
--targets S3Targets=[
{Path="s3://DOC-EXAMPLE-BUCKET/sentiment-results"},
{Path="s3://DOC-EXAMPLE-BUCKET/entities-results"}] 
--database-name comprehend-results
```

Look carefully that you are stating `--targets "JdbcTargets"` and it looks like it should be `--targets JdbcTargets=[`

Comment: Thanks @Ikaro0 Added one more param to JdbcTargets as 'Path'-->

--targets JdbcTargets=[{ConnectionName="RS_Connection"},{Path="awsuser\public\tutorial_tbl"}]

here 

awsuser = DB Name
public = schema
tutorial_tbl=Table Name which needs to be crawled

it's now giving below error 

"An error occurred (InvalidInputException) when calling the CreateCrawler operation: Connection name cannot be equal to null or empty."

Comment: Can you update your initial post with the new code for anyone that came here to watch your question?

Comment: @ColinMorenoBurgess I checked the docs, but couldn't find how to write multiple parameters for targets, for example: `DynamoDBTargets=[{Path="QA_186_AIJob",scanAll=“true”,scanRate=“1.5”}`. This results in `Unknown options: DynamoDBTargets=[scanRate=“1.5”], DynamoDBTargets=[scanAll=“true”]`. Can you please tell how to solve this?

Comment: I think is because you are not passing a true json format from the documentation I think it should be something like --targets {   "DynamoDBTargets": [
    {
      "Path": "string",
      "scanAll": true|false,
      "scanRate": double
    } }]} as shown here, https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/glue/create-crawler.html notice  that after --targets everything is enclosed in {}